# How to calculate the peak width from a graph given the peaks

Tags: python

I have a graph that is

picture of graph

[image: picture of graph]

and I need to find the peak width between the peaks, I have the peaks actual value, and I need a code to calculate it and plot it on the graph

this is my code so far

```
import pylab 
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_prominences, peak_widths


#empty lists 
X_list = []
Y_list = []

with open("XRD_example1_edit.txt") as inputfile:
# for loop 
    for line in inputfile:
#splitting the columns and float the numbers and remove the asterik 
        column = line.split()
        x = (float(column[0]))
        y = (float(column[1].replace("*","")))
        X_list.append(x)
        Y_list.append(y)

# printing the lists 
#print(X_list)
#print(Y_list)

# graphing the function 

#pylab.plot(X_list,Y_list)

#pylab.show()

# to get half peak intenstities 


# Find peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(Y_list)
prominences, left_bases, right_bases = peak_prominences(Y_list, peaks)

# Create constant offset as a replacement for prominences
offset = np.ones_like(prominences)

# Calculate widths at x[peaks] - offset * rel_height
widths, h_eval, left_ips, right_ips = peak_widths(
    Y_list, peaks, 
    rel_height=1,
    prominence_data=(offset, left_bases, right_bases)
)

# Check that h_eval is 1 everywhere
#np.testing.assert_equal(Y_list[peaks] - h_eval, 1)

# Visualize result

pylab.plot(X_list,Y_list)
pylab.plot(peaks,Y_list[peaks], "x")
pylab.hlines(h_eval, left_ips, right_ips, color="C2")
pylab.show()
```

The problem that I am having is my data is an array and the peaks in the data have these # symbols to denote the peaks, so when I first ran the array I removed them so I could graph it, so I need to figure out how to get back the original data from this file and then using the values with the # to find the half-height peak width

Some of the data from the long list of data I have is ...

```
12.16   98.27408102
12.18   99.76437208
12.2    100#
12.22   99.44131752
12.24   97.88960572
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question (which in turn improves your chances of getting a (good) answer).

Comment: Take a look at [`scipy.signal.peak_widths`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_widths.html).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the link, I am a beginner, and I don't have much experience with python, so I see the functions are there, but I don't know how to implement them successfully

Comment: Please add example data in order to make your example reproducible.

Comment: instead of removing the #, can you somehow copy the data in a new array without the #? No need to completely lose that info!

Comment: Hi, I have just added some data to the original question,